# Cookies are not loading first time in Gatsby with gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies and react-cookie-consent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

**explanation:**

This code works (with gatsby develop or gatsby build && gatsby serve), but if I do my code without  onAccept={() => window.location.reload()} is not working properly because just load my cookie -> (gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics = true) but  are not loading ga cookies at the same time, and I have to refresh with onAccept. Any idea how to load all cookies same time without forcing a refresh?

**my code:**

// gatsby-config.js

```
 {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`,
      options: {
        googleAnalytics: {
          trackingId: 'my_tracking_id', // leave empty if you want to disable the tracker
          cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics', // default
          includeInDevelopment: true,
          head: true
        },
        // defines the environments where the tracking should be available  - default is ["production"]
        environments: ['production', 'development']
      },
    },
```

// index.js

```
import CookieConsent from "react-cookie-consent";

 <CookieConsent
        overlay
        id="#consentModal"
        location="bottom"
        buttonText="ACCEPT"
        declineButtonText="DECLINE"
        cookieName="gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics"
        expires={150}
        enableDeclineButton
        style={{
          background: "black",
          display: "flex",
          padding: "10px"
        }}
        buttonStyle={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          background: "#fff",
          color: "red",
          borderRadius: "4px",
          justifyContent: "middle",
          width: "85px",
        }}
        declineButtonStyle={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          background: "#ff5f56",
          borderRadius: "4px",
          color: "#fff",
          cursor: "pointer",
          width: "85px"
        }}
        onAccept={() => window.location.reload()} //I would like to remove this refresh
      >
        <p style={{ float: "left", }}> my text </p>
        <p style={{ float: "left", }}>my text</p>
      </CookieConsent>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
import CookieConsent from "react-cookie-consent";
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router" 
import { initializeAndTrack } from 'gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies'
    
<CookieConsent
        overlay
        id="#consentModal"
        location="bottom"
        buttonText="ACCEPT"
        declineButtonText="DECLINE"
        cookieName="gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics"
        expires={150}
        enableDeclineButton
        style={{
          background: "black",
          display: "flex",
          padding: "10px"
        }}
        buttonStyle={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          background: "#fff",
          color: "red",
          borderRadius: "4px",
          justifyContent: "middle",
          width: "85px",
        }}
        declineButtonStyle={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          background: "#ff5f56",
          borderRadius: "4px",
          color: "#fff",
          cursor: "pointer",
          width: "85px"
        }}
        onAccept={() => {
          initializeAndTrack(location) 
        }}
      >
        <p style={{ float: "left", }}> my text </p>
        <p style={{ float: "left", }}>my text</p>
      </CookieConsent>
```

`gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies` supports [tracking without refreshing the page using some built-in consumers](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/#initialize-and-track).

Once the helpers are imported, you can execute `initializeAndTrack(location)` in your cookie banner callback. This will initialize the plugin with your options from the `gatsby-config.js` and then starts tracking the user based on the cookies/services are accepted.

Comment: where do you put the `const location = useLocation();` because I am doing this in gatsby-browser currently and it throws an error

Comment: Do you mean `import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"`?

Comment: I moved my cookie consent to a component and now this part is not erroring. 
The initializeAndTrack does not seem to work however. Google Tag Manager is not initialised until the route changes or page is refreshed after accepting the cookies (which fires `onAccept={() => { initializeAndTrack(location) }}` just like the answer above

Comment: This is how the library works. From the docs: "This plugin will fire a new event called `gatsbyRouteChange` (by default) on Gatsby’s `onRouteUpdate` (only if the consent was given by a visitor)". Feel free to open a new answer rather than commenting on a specific implementation.